# Cocoapods not finding static library during lint

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a project here:
https://github.com/johanlantz/curly

that relies on another opensource project called "curl". To simplify things I have precompiled curl and saved the libcurl.a in the subfolder: third-party/curl/ios/lib

When I use my "curly" project from a standard podfile simply including it like this:

pod 'curly', :git => 'https://github.com/johanlantz/curly.git', :tag => '0.4.0'

Everything works fine. However now I want to add it to the public pod directory and to do that it must pass the lint process but it does not.

If you clone https://github.com/johanlantz/curly.git and run:

pod spec lint curly.podspec --verbose

you will see that the linker complains about not finding the prebuilt curl library, the error is:

ld: library not found for -lcurl

The podspec does define the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS and again, it does work when using this pod from a Podfile (I also do not see any -L with this path in the output from the podspec lint but I am not sure if that is normal or not).

I am using the latest version of "pod" updated today.

The problem is easily reproducible by simply cloning my project and running the lint command.

Any ideas on why the library search path is not working would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally this was me forgetting to add the --use-libraries to the lint command.

Problem solved